# find the lowest number in json value and find the value of that key

Tags: python

I have `file.json`:

```json
[
    {
        "name": "personA",
        "valA": 2,
        "valB": 0
    },
    {
        "name": "personB",
        "valA": 3,
        "valB": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "personC",
        "valA": 2,
        "valB": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "personD",
        "valA": 5,
        "valB": 3
    }
]
```

This is python code:

```py
with open('file.json', 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

valA_numbers = []
for valA in data:
    valA_numbers.append(valA['valA'])

min_number = min(tuple(valA_numbers))
```

This is logic I have:

> Open `file.json` and see who has the least `valA` value. Increment that +1 and print the related `name` should do today's `valA`.

With my python code we, `min_number = 2`. I increment it by 1, but I don't know how to determine if this `2` belongs to `personA` or `personC`.

I expect to have this:

> Number 2 belongs to `personA`.

Comment: Shouldn't you be looking for `valA = 3` since the instructions say to increment by one?

Comment: @Unmitigated why? 3 isn't the lowest here. Did I understand correct?

Comment: @Saeed The instructions you provided say "Increment that [the minimum] +1 and print the related name".

Answer (score 0):

Create variables to keep track of the smallest valA and its name.

Initialize these variables with the first item in the list:

```
smallest_valA = data[0]['valA']
smallest_name = data[0]['name']
```

Then iterate over all the remaining items, updating `smallest_valA` and `smallest_name` whenever you find a smaller value:

```
for d in data[1:]:
    if d['valA'] < smallest_valA:
        # this item is the new smallest
        smallest_valA = d['valA']
        smallest_name = d['name']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `next` with a generator expression to find the person whose `valA` is `1` more than the minimum.

```py
min_a = min(item['valA'] for item in data)
person = next(item for item in data if item['valA'] == min_a + 1)
```